# Date.getHours() in JavaScript looks broken to me

Tags: javascript, datetime

This snippet displays 1. Why is it so?

I use constructor as in `new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01`. I expect it to be midnight, so 0 hours. But why does it return 1?

```
var milliseconds = 0;
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
alert(d.getHours());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you in timezone GMT+1?

Answer (score 3):

```
var milliseconds = 0;
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
alert(d.getUTCHours()); // returns 0
```